# Detect if react-native project is being run on Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I need to support expo in one of my open-source projects. I would like to load a specific module when the project is being run on Expo otherwise load another module and work with that.
One of the solutions would be using `resolve('module')` to check if the specific module is available or not, but my question is, is there any other ways to detect if the project is based on Expo or not?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @dcangulo Unfortunately, not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now they deprecated the accepted answer in favor of using the `require` keyword and wrapping it into a try/catch block. A little example:

```
let camera;
try {
  camera = require("expo-camera");
} catch {
  camera = require("another-camera-package");
}
module.exports = camera;
```

Reference: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/expo-extension-migration.md#before

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the answer, this is what worked for me.

Instead of doing this:

```
const expo = true;
let something;

if (expo) something = require('expo');
else {
  const { NativeModules } = require('react-native');
  something = NativeModules.MyNativeModule.something;
}

// use something here
```

I used a [custom file extension (.expo.js)](https://docs.expo.io/bare/using-expo-client/#use-the--expojsjsontstsx--extension-to).

Vanilla:

```
// MyComponent.js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { something } = NativeModules.MyNativeModule;

// use something here
```

Expo:

```
// MyComponent.expo.js
import something from 'expo';

// use something here
```

Expo will automatically use the `.expo.js` file.

Comment: Ahh, nice! I didn't know Expo has its own extension.

Comment: This will not work from expo sdk 41. https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/master/expo-extension-migration.md#migration-off-the-expo-file-extension